# Screen autorotation not working on Ubuntu 22LTS when using Wayland

Tags: 22.04, wayland, tablet, display-rotation, orientation

Automatic screen rotation on Ubuntu 22.0 not working, when using „Wayland“. Also there is no screen rotation lock button in upper right menu. When I run „monitor-sensor“ and rotate computer, it correctly identify screen orientation:

```
Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
```

Also, if I chose „xorg“ in login screen, autorotation working normal. Is it possible to enable autorotation in Wayland?